# Can't get value to be written to csv file with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Before I get started, I just wanted to say that my knowledge of python isn't the largest in the world :) But I try to manage. To give a small introduction, the issue i'm having here is actually with a script I had custom built 1,5 years ago and I now want to use for another (similar) purpose.

The script used to gather data from hashtags (hence all the tags references), and I now 'remodeled' it, to gather Top post data from locations.

The issue I'm having is that, while the top post data is being correctly exported to the csv, I wanted to add the post count, but that isn't working.

I Google'd around for quite a while and inserted the count parameter on various lines and possibilities, but can't seem to fix it.

I'd be super glad if anyone could assist me in fixing this.

So without further text, here's the source code of my Python script:

```
import csv
import requests


def get_csv_header(top_numb):
    fieldnames = ['LOCATION_ID','MEDIA_COUNT']
    for col in range(top_numb):
        fieldnames.append('TOP_{0}_LIKE'.format(col + 1))
        fieldnames.append('TOP_{0}_COMMENT'.format(col + 1))
    return fieldnames


def write_csv_header(filename, headers):
    with open(filename, 'w', newline='') as f_out:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(f_out, fieldnames=headers)
        writer.writeheader()
    return


def read_hash_tag(t_file):
    with open(t_file) as f:
        tags_list = f.read().splitlines()
    return tags_list

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # HERE YOU CAN SPECIFIC YOUR TAG FILE NAME,
    # Which contains a list of hash tags, BY DEFAULT <current working directory>/tags.txt
    TAGS_FILE = 'ids.txt'
    # HERE YOU CAN SPECIFIC YOUR DATA FILE NAME, BY DEFAULT (data.csv)', Where your final result stays
    DATA_FILE = 'data.csv'
    MAX_POST = 9  # MAX POST

    """ Start scraping inst for like and comment based on hash tags """

    print('Job starts, please wait until it finishes.....')
    explore_url = 'https://www.instagram.com/explore/locations/'
    tags = read_hash_tag(TAGS_FILE)

    """ Writing data to csv file """
    csv_headers = get_csv_header(MAX_POST)
    write_csv_header(DATA_FILE, csv_headers)

    for tag in tags:
        post_info = {'LOCATION_ID': tag}
        url = explore_url + tag + '/'
        params = {'__a': 1}
        try:
            response = requests.get(url, params=params).json()
        except ValueError:
            print('ValueError for location id {0}...Skipping...'.format(tag))
            continue
        media_count = response['graphql']['location']['edge_location_to_media']['count']
        top_posts = response['graphql']['location']['edge_location_to_top_posts']['edges']
        for num, post in enumerate(top_posts):
            if num + 1 <= MAX_POST:
                post_info['TOP_{0}_LIKE'.format(num + 1)] = post['node']['edge_liked_by']['count']
                post_info['TOP_{0}_COMMENT'.format(num + 1)] = post['node']['edge_media_to_comment']['count']
            else:
                break
        with open('data.csv', 'a', newline='') as data_out:
            print('Writing Data for location id {0}.....'.format(tag))
            print(media_count)
            csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(data_out, fieldnames=csv_headers)
            csv_writer.writerow(post_info)

    """ Done with the script """
    print('ALL DONE !!!! ')
```

This is the output in CMD:

> C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads>locations.py Job starts, please wait
>   until it finishes..... 
>   Writing Data for location id 213226563.....
>   1346216 
>   Writing Data for location id 919359..... 
>   56752 
>   ALL DONE !!!!

The values 1346216  and 56752  are the media count for those locations and are in fact correct.

But whenever I open my csv that's being built, I don't see the value stored in there:

```
    LOCATION_ID,MEDIA_COUNT,TOP_1_LIKE,TOP_1_COMMENT,TOP_2_LIKE,TOP_2_COMMENT,TOP_3_LIKE,TOP_3_COMMENT,TOP_4_LIKE,TOP_4_COMMENT,TOP_5_LIKE,TOP_5_COMMENT,TOP_6_LIKE,TOP_6_COMMENT,TOP_7_LIKE,TOP_7_COMMENT,TOP_8_LIKE,TOP_8_COMMENT,TOP_9_LIKE,TOP_9_COMMENT
    213226563,,551,21,288,51,796,27,346,7,329,44,8641,181,507,32,1513,31,432,12
    919359,,456,1,265,7,771,0,815,9,79,2,107,5,116,1,95,1,153,3
```

I know it's not the most elegant / sexy solution. But any help in getting my media count inside the csv file in column 2 would be grand!

Comment: "I wanted to add the post count, but that isn't working." This wording implies that you have some code that you think should add the post count, but isn't. I don't see anything that would do so. What were you expecting to add the post count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never add media_count to post_info, which is the dictionary that gets written to the csv.

This change in the write part should fix your problem:

```
with open('data.csv', 'a', newline='') as data_out:
    print('Writing Data for location id {0}.....'.format(tag))
    print(media_count)

    post_info["MEDIA_COUNT"] = media_count       

    csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(data_out, fieldnames=csv_headers)
    csv_writer.writerow(post_info)
```

Comment: Rookie mistake! :') Thanks for the super quick response! <3